# Minimize the query time of MySQL except Indexing

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing software engineering research on Auto-completion. So, the access time is very crucial in this field.

I have stored almost 10,000 source code's method body in MySQL database and it takes almost 10 minutes. The configuration of my laptop is core i3, 2.4GHz dual core, 4GB RAM.

The database has tables and each table contains primary key which is actually doing the indexing in MySQL. Now, whenever I do a single query with primary key, it takes almost 500ms.

**Now my question  - Is there any method or strategy except indexing in MySQL that can minimize query time on primary key ?**

EDIT: OP add information in comment section:

The schema is very simple. It has only one table and the field is id(int),body(TEXT),className(varchar). The primary key is ID. The query is:

```
select body,className from table where id=100
```

Comment: Querying by primary key should be very fast, since the primary key is always indexed. Please show your database schema and the query you're using.

Comment: The schema is very simple. It has only one table and the field is id(int),body(TEXT),className(varchar). The primary key is ID.
The query is "select body,className from table where id=100"

Comment: There's no reason for that to take 500 ms. What does `EXPLAIN` say?

Comment: How big is the database? Does it fit easily in RAM?

Comment: Is your machine IO bound?

Comment: How big is each method-string?

Comment: Noted that, I am using JDBC for accessing mysql database. I have extracted method body and other preprocessing and therefore it takes almost 10 minutes to insert into the database.
But a single query mentioned previous command takes almost 500ms.

Comment: There are almost 600,000 methods in the database, that means 600,000 rows.

Comment: Maybe you should tune `innodb_buffer_pool_size`